# Sending Files using Python Socket: The connection is closed too soon

Tags: python, python-sockets

I currently have a server (Perl) and a client (PHP) implementation that is able to send files, from the client to the server. Those systems has been working without problem for over 5 years, so I am quite confident that the implementation is correct.

I need to replace the PHP implementation by a python one. I have written the client code to send a file in python, such as:

```
    self._sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self._sock.connect((host, port))

    hash_md5 = hashlib.md5()
    f = open(file_source_full_path, 'rb')
    chunk = f.read(1024)
    while chunk:
        self._sock.send(chunk)
        hash_md5.update(chunk)
        chunk = f.read(1024)

    f.close()
    self.log.debug("MD5 %s  ..." % hash_md5.hexdigest())

    self._sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
    self._sock.close()
```

This implementation is currently working correctly for small files. If the file is large (eg 1.6 Mb) it does not work. Not all the data gets transferred - it transfers something between 1.1 and 1.3 Mb.

According to the MD5 check, all the file is actually sent, but some data is lost somewhere I and I can't understand what it is.

Any help to fix or to debug the problem wold be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I just performed some additional debug. All the data is sent by the client, but once stops sending data and closes the connection the server stops receiving the data that is in transit.

I have found a workaround to this problem: if I add a `time.sleep(5)` right before `self._sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)` it works as expected.

How can I properly wait for all the information to be received by the client?

Comment: Socket `send` returns the number of bytes actually sent, which may be less than the amount you've asked it to send. Either make sure you check that value, or use `sendall` instead, that will block until everything is sent out (or throw, if it fails to do so).

Comment: @BorisLipschitz please check the update. Somehow Python is closing the connection to soon. If I add an `time.sleep(5)` the data transfer work

Comment: Remove the shutdown and just close it at the end?

Comment: @BorisLipschitz removing the shutdown does not make any effect. Same problem, the connection gets closed before all the data is actually transferred.

Comment: Sorry, i really don't know whats going on then.